# message-driven-channel-adapter with backoff to stop process

Tags: spring, spring-integration

We use spring integration to transfer messages from ibm mq to RabbitMQ.
This works well, however we would like to optimize the handling of exceptions when consuming messages.

Below the code to read messages from JMS:

```
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory" >
      <property name="queueManager" value="${MQ_INBOUND_QUEUE_MANAGER_NAME}" />
      <property name="hostName" value="${MQ_INBOUND_HOSTNAME}" />
      <property name="port" value="${MQ_INBOUND_PORT}" />
      <property name="channel" value="${MQ_INBOUND_CHANNEL_NAME}" />
      <property name="transportType" value="1" />
</bean>
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory_cred"
    class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="username" value="${MQ_INBOUND_USER}"/> 
    <property name="password" value="${MQ_INBOUND_PASSWORD}"/> 
</bean> 
<bean id="connectionFactoryCaching" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
      <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory_cred" />
      <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="${MQ_INBOUND_SESSION_CACHE}" />
</bean> 
<bean id="jmsQueue" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue" depends-on="jmsConnectionFactory">
    <property name="encoding" value="${MQ_INBOUND_ENCODING}"></property>
    <property name="CCSID" value="${MQ_INBOUND_CCSID}"></property>
    <property name="priority" value="${MQ_INBOUND_PRIORITY}"></property>
    <property name="persistence" value="${MQ_INBOUND_PERSISTENCE}"></property>      
    <property name="baseQueueManagerName" value="${MQ_INBOUND_QUEUE_MANAGER_NAME}" />
    <property name="baseQueueName" value="${MQ_INBOUND_QUEUE_NAME}" />
    <property name="targetClient" value="1" />
</bean>
<bean id="txMq"
        class="org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactoryCaching" />
</bean>      
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="jmsIn" 
    connection-factory="connectionFactoryCaching" 
    destination="jmsQueue" 
    channel="channelMQ_RMQ" 
    transaction-manager="txMq"  
    error-channel="processChannel1"/>
```

If an error occurs on the connection (non-existent Queue_Manager for example), there is an automatic retry (with maxAttempts=unlimited) to reconnect on the Queue Manager.

We would like to use the `int-jms: message-driven-channel-adapter` by adding a `Backoff` mecanism in order to limit the retry as in the example below and then stop the thread:

```
CachingConnectionFactory ccf = new CachingConnectionFactory(cfCredentialsAdapter);

DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
container.setConnectionFactory(ccf);
container.setDestinationName(QUEUE_NAME);


FixedBackOff backoff = new FixedBackOff(2000,  3);
container.setBackOff(backoff);
```

How to pass this `Backoff` to the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` generated by the `message-driven-channel-adapter` bean?

Thanks for your help

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can declare that `ListenerContainer` as a bean and use it from the mentioned channel adapter definition via this attribute:

```
<xsd:attribute name="container" type="xsd:string">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation><![CDATA[
        A reference to a custom listener container implementation.
        Note that a custom container class will typically be a subclass of DefaultMessageListenerContainer.
        This attribute is mutually exclusive with 'container-class'.
                    ]]></xsd:documentation>
                    <xsd:appinfo>
                        <tool:annotation kind="ref">
                            <tool:expected-type
                                    type="org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer"/>
                        </tool:annotation>
                    </xsd:appinfo>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:attribute>
```

So, no need to seek a back-off option since we can just simply go ahead with traditional `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` configuration and its reference from the channel adapter.
Of course, all other options must go from the channel adapter to the container definition.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Artem for your advice.
This works fine, with the retry my thread ends well after the good number of retry.

```
<bean id="fixedBackOff" class="org.springframework.util.backoff.FixedBackOff">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="2000" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="3" />
</bean>

<bean id="myListener" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer" >
    <property name="autoStartup" value="false" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactoryCaching" />
    <property name="destination" ref="jmsQueue" />
    <property name="maxMessagesPerTask" value="1" />
    <property name="receiveTimeout" value="1" />
    <property name="backOff" ref="fixedBackOff" />
</bean>

<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="jmsIn"
    container="myListener"
    channel="channelMQ_RMQ"
    error-channel="processChannel1"/>
```

Is it possible to detect the output of the bean to log the stop of retries, as it works well when using the `error-channel`

```
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="processChannel1"  />
<int:logging-channel-adapter channel="processChannel1" logger-name="log1" level="INFO" expression="payload"/>
<int:service-activator input-channel="processChannel1"  ref="channelUtils" output-channel="error1" method="kill" />
```

Regards,

Eric